# Changing file extensions within a XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

This one is a bit of a tricky one.  I have a contents.xml file that references a host of other files.  These other files use to be .xml, and have been altered to .dita, my question is how can i renames all the .xml file extensions to .dita?  The file paths are a varying levels in the tree and have an inconsistent number of subfolders in front of them.
Example:

```
<article
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

   <title>Definition</title>
   <xi:include href="./introduction.xml"/>
   <section xml:id="viewComponents"><title>View Components</title>
      <xi:include href="./components/page.xml"/>
      <xi:include href="./views/sheet.xml"/>
      <xi:include href="./folder/xsubfolders/plaque.xml"/>
   </section>
</article>
```

To:

```
<article
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

   <title>Definition</title>
   <xi:include href="./introduction.dita"/>
   <section xml:id="viewComponents"><title>View Components</title>
      <xi:include href="./components/page.dita"/>
      <xi:include href="./views/sheet.dita"/>
      <xi:include href="./folder/xsubfolders/plaque.dita"/>
   </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and complete solution. :)

Comment: I'm confused as to why the the answers are all stylesheets. Why not just create a quick script that will find the string ".xml" and replace it with ".dita"?

Comment: @RyanJM: Could it be because the question is tagged with `xslt`? Could it be because you can have an element named `this.xml`?

Comment: @RyanJM: This question can be "tricky" only if you want to solve it not with XSLT :) This explains why there are plenty of XSLT answers and why you got plenty of them in no time :)

Comment: @RyanJM: You shouldn't replace all occurences of ".xml" with ".dita". Maybe "a quick script" could do that, but this would be a grossly wrong "solution". Try first to understand the problem.

Comment: :) I get the point. Thank you for explaining. @Dimitre the reason I asked the question in a comment was because I was trying to understand the problem more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "xi:include/@href[substring(., string-length()-3)='.xml']">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1, string-length()-3),'dita')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<article
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

   <title>Definition</title>
   <xi:include href="./introduction.xml"/>
   <section xml:id="viewComponents"><title>View Components</title>
      <xi:include href="./components/page.xml"/>
      <xi:include href="./views/sheet.xml"/>
      <xi:include href="./folder/xsubfolders/plaque.xml"/>
   </section>
</article>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<article xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <title>Definition</title>
    <xi:include href="./introduction.dita"></xi:include>
    <section xml:id="viewComponents">
        <title>View Components</title>
        <xi:include href="./components/page.dita"></xi:include>
        <xi:include href="./views/sheet.dita"></xi:include>
        <xi:include href="./folder/xsubfolders/plaque.dita"></xi:include>
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring(string(.), string-length(string(.)) - 3) = '.xml'">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(string(.), 1, string-length(string(.)) - 4), '.dita')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="./node()|./@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template at the bottom copies all input directly to the output, with the exception of attributes which are picked up by the template above, and the text transform is applied here.

Comment: Your answer is almost identical to that of @Alejandro. Both are slightly incorrect (not sufficiently precise).

Comment: WTF?!?!?  Slightly incorrect how?  My stylesheet does the exact transform that was asked for it, and my response was posted first.  Why the hell am I downvoted for this?!

Comment: It was not me, who downvoted you. I don't know why you were downvoted. When you downvote another person just based on suspicion that he might have downvoted you, this only exposes your character. I truly pitty such people.